# multiple selectpicker get unsort order value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This code is working fine. In the multiple select:

but i want to get value in unsort form like if i select first time number value and second times select DD so value should be like `=[num],[dd]` but default value showing = `[dd],[num]`

```
<select name="select_dropdown" id="select_dropdown" class="select_seach form-control" onchange="Changedropdownvalue()" multiple data-selected-text-format="count > 3" >
  <option value="">Select Reference Format Order</option>
  <option value="[dd]">DD</option>
  <option value="[mm]">MM</option>
  <option value="[yy]">YY</option>
  <option value="[num]">Number</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do some manual process in `click` function and store an array for selected values in order like

```
var sel_arr = [];
$("#select_dropdown").on("click", function(e){
  if($(this).find("option:selected").length == 0) {
    sel_arr = [];
  } else if($(this).find("option:selected").length == 1) {
    sel_arr = [$(this).find("option:selected").val()];
  } else {
    var val = e.target.value;
    if ($.inArray(val, sel_arr) > -1) {
      sel_arr.splice( $.inArray(val, sel_arr), 1 );
    } else {
      sel_arr.push(val);
    }
  }

  console.log(sel_arr);
});
```

Note that you need to call `sel_arr` global var whenever you need to use selected values. And no need to say this is gonna only work for `click`, not any other `change` methods.

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/n7xbdwv1/)